# Unable to get the Messages in STORM NEW VERSION(1.0.1) from the BEGINNING

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, apache-kafka, apache-storm

We are trying to get messages in kafka from beginning using **STORM VERSION 0.9.3** and we are able to put it in HBASE TABLE.

For that the configuration which we used is:

```
kafkaConfig.forceFromStart = true;
```

So we were getting the messages from **OFFSET 0** i.e from starting in hbase table i.e complete messages.

But when we are trying to get messages from beginning in kafka using **STORM VERSION 1.0.1** and trying to put it in HBASE TABLE, we are getting the last messages only. We are not getting the message from the beginning that is **OFFSET 0** (i.e the lastly added message were able to get it but not from the beginning).

The configuration which we used:

```
kafkaConfig.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
kafkaConfig.useStartOffsetTimeIfOffsetOutOfRange = true;
kafkaConfig.startOffsetTime = kafka.api.OffsetRequest.EarliestTime();
kafkaConfig.ignoreZkOffsets = false;
kafkaConfig.maxOffsetBehind = Long.MAX_VALUE;
kafkaConfig.startOffsetTime = -2;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set the ignoreZkOffsets to true if you want to force the consumer to use specified offset instead of reading it from Zookeeper.

From the documentation of [storm-kafka](https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/external/storm-kafka#how-kafkaspout-stores-offsets-of-a-kafka-topic-and-recovers-in-case-of-failures):

> This means that when a topology has run once the setting
>   KafkaConfig.startOffsetTime will not have an effect for subsequent
>   runs of the topology because now the topology will rely on the
>   consumer state information (offsets) in ZooKeeper to determine from
>   where it should begin (more precisely: resume) reading. If you want to
>   force the spout to ignore any consumer state information stored in
>   ZooKeeper, then you should set the parameter
>   KafkaConfig.ignoreZkOffsets to true. If true, the spout will always
>   begin reading from the offset defined by KafkaConfig.startOffsetTime
>   as described above.

So for consuming messages from beginning of the queue, use the below config:

```
kafkaConfig.ignoreZkOffsets = true;
kafkaConfig.startOffsetTime = kafka.api.OffsetRequest.EarliestTime();
```

Comment: But we have already set this configuration in our code and also we tried to set kafkaConfig.startOffsetTime=-2;..we are able to read all msgs from kafka but while inserting it in hbase table only last msg is insterted...any help..